# Is it possible to get "average record save" time for a specific SObject type?

Tags: apex, performance

We are optimizing our existing code base using a set of frameworks. We want to measure, how these improved the performance of a transaction.
Is there a way to check average record save time in Salesforce? I know, we can analyze debug log in Dev Console. But that will be just for a specific record. We want to understand the average time taken?

Comment: SFDC Event Monitoring (paid extra item) can give you a wealth of performance data

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this kind of data would not be available even via SF support case. You should rather look at identifying the transactions that are taking a lot of time and measure the execution time before and after optimization. Given below are some reasons why SF might not have the kind of data you are looking for:

- Your code should have been bulkified already and DML is just one of the executions within a single apex transaction. Since, the DML would execute for a collection of records, `system.debug` of DML execution timestamp will also not help you find the average statistics you are looking for.
- Traditional Databases store every kind of data (for example, accounts, orders, contacts etc. which is equivalent to SObject in Salesforce) in separate DB tables. Salesforce is on the cloud/ multi-tenant architecture and unlike traditional databases, the SObjects are stored as metadata across few DB tables (rather than storing them in individual DB tables). *This is essential for SF to  be able to provide a configurable platform with lot of OOB features*. So, your DML on any SObject (accounts, contacts etc.) are going to be inserted or updated on the same set of DB tables. Salesforce DB team might monitor these DB tables (which are quite confidential at detailed level), but I doubt they monitor any statistics are individual SObject level.
- Salesforce DB deals with millions or billions of records every minute which span across many instances, orgs and sobjects, so picking up statistics at record level DML might be tricky to capture (at the least would be difficult).

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your detailed reply.